# Question about known limit if x is negative?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

We know that

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$$

so

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \ln(1+x)=x$$

Can I conclude that

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}=1$$
and

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \ln(1-x)=-x$$

Is it correct?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{x\to 0} \ln(1+x)=x$?

Comment: The variable $s$ on the right hand side is out of scope.

Comment: The fourth line has no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can say is that $\ln(1 + x) \sim x$ as $x\to 0$, so
$\ln(1 -x) \sim -x$ as $x\to 0$. This is the proper notation.